$slot undefined varaiable using livewire components with laravel 11
This is the code that I tried to create a login form with reusable components. I want to render the button component with an icon, but when I pass the slot, I get an error.
App/livewire/Button.php
@php
$classValueVariants = [
  'default' =>
      'w-full max-w-sm py-3 px-4 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-semibold rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none peer',
  'icon' =>
      'py-3 px-4 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-semibold rounded-lg border disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none peer',
];
@endphp

<div>
  @if ($tag == 'button')
    <button type="{{ $type }}" class="{{ $customClass }} {{ $classValueVariants[$buttonType] }}">
        {{ $value }}
        <div class="inline-block">{!! $slot !!}</div>
    </button>
  @elseif ($tag == 'link')
    <a class="{{ $classValueVariants[$buttonType] }} {{ $customClass }}">
        {{ $value }}
        <div class="inline-block">{!! $slot !!}</div>
    </a>
  @endif
</div>

livewire/login-form.php
{{-- !Separator --}}

<div class="w-full max-w-sm flex gap-2 justify-evenly items-center">
    <livewire:button button-type="icon" type="submit" tag="button"
        custom-class="text-center border-2 bg-blue-600" href="/auth/github">
        <x-fab-github class="w-7 h-7 text-white" />
    </livewire:button>

    <livewire:button
        button-type="icon"
        type="submit"
        custom-class="text-center border-2 bg-blue-600"
        value="Connect with Slack"
    >
        <x-fab-slack class="w-7 h-7 text-white bg-red-500" />
    </livewire:button>

    <livewire:button button-type="icon" type="submit" custom-class="text-center border-2 bg-blue-600">
        <x-fab-google class="w-7 h-7 text-white" />
    </livewire:button>
</div>
{{-- !title --}}


I am not aware that Livewire natively supports slots. Look here

$slot is a Blade component feature.
If you read the Livewire docs carefully, you will see that $slot is only used in the layout files of Livewire, which is a Blade component.
Pass all required data via attributes.

Yes i fixed the problem , create component by make:component in my views folder by the  same name and delete the livewire component [ button and inpu-form ]
